# Play framework: Slick does not know how to map the given types

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, slick, play-slick

I am trying to use slick in the play framework but struggling with even the simplest of examples.

Here is my code:

```
case class Account (
  id: Int,
  email: String,
  password: String,
  permission: String
)

class Accounts(tag: Tag) extends Table[Account](tag, "account") {
  def id = column[Int]("id")
  def email = column[String]("email")
  def password = column[String]("password")
  def permission = column[String]("permission")

  def * = (id, email, password, permission)
}
```

When I compile this I get the following error:

```
play.PlayExceptions$CompilationException: Compilation error[No matching Shape found.
Slick does not know how to map the given types.
Possible causes: T in Table[T] does not match your * projection. Or you use an unsupported type in a Query (e.g. scala List).
  Required level: scala.slick.lifted.ShapeLevel.Flat
     Source type: (scala.slick.lifted.Column[Int], scala.slick.lifted.Column[String], scala.slick.lifted.Column[String], scala.slick.lifted.Column[String])
   Unpacked type: models.Account
     Packed type: Any
]
```

Can anyone tell me if I have something wrong here?

Thanks

Further Details:

- Scala 2.10
- Slick 2.0.2
- Play-slick 0.6.0.1
- Play Framework 2.3.1

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I have found the issue. I have a companion object that was conflicting

If you have a companion object you need to use a slightly different syntax for your * projection:

```
def * = (id, email, password, permission) <> ((Account.apply _).tupled, Account.unapply)
```

Comment: I'm using the same syntax and it's not working for me. Not sure if I'm missing something. I do have some Timestamp fields, maybe I'm missing some sort of mapping?

Answer (score 3):

according to http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.0.2/schemas.html, I think that you "*" projection method should look like this:

```
def * = (id, email, password, permission) <> (Account.tupled, Account.unapply)
```

Comment: Thanks Pawel. I tried that as well but I get this error: value tupled is not a member of object models.Account